# Cache locale specific templates in Thyemeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Apparently Thymeleaf doesn't use locale as part of the cache key.
This is causing issue for a particular use case.
 - Many locale specific fragments exists which contains static text that are too big to be part of messages.properties file. They are stored in hierarchy similar to following:

```
+ templates
+--> help.html

+
+--> fragments
+
+----> en
+-------> help-index.html
+
+----> es
+-------> help-index.html
+
+----> fr
+-------> help-index.html
...
```

- The "help.html" page template then include this fragment as

  th:include="fragments/help-index :: imp-block"
- A custom resource resolver handles the resolving of the template based on the incoming request locale.
- The problem is when caching is turned on, Thymeleaf caches the first request's locale specific fragment.

Adding locale as part of the fragment name will work, but that is less than ideal for me.

Is it possible to solve this problem differently?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your resource resolver is hiding the locale, that's why the cache key is the same for all languages. Maybe I don't understand the problem, but why don't you just included the language in the include path like 'fragments/'+${lang}+'/help-index'!?